# jscript function pointer

Tags: javascript, wsh

In MS JScript I can write

```
WSH.Echo("hello world");
```

And run it through command line cscript.exe which works as expected.

But if I want to use the function print() for printing, one solution is to assign the target function to a variable called print, like this, which works with most JS interpreter

```
var print=WSH.Echo
print("hello world");
```

But that doesn't work with cscript.exe and prints the following error message

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any shortcut way to achieve it without writing individual wrapper function for each function that I want to rename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context of the function being called is changing. If the `Echo` function contains a relative reference to `this`, you'll need to call the function in the context of the WSH object. A simple solution is to just use a wrapper function:

```
var print = function (param)
{
  WSH.Echo(param);
};
```

Now, of course that sucks for doing repetitively, so you'll want to make a wrapper generator:

```
function alias(fn, context)
{
  return function(param)
  {
    context[fn](param);
  };
}

var print = alias('Echo', WSQ);
```

This is just a simple example, you should be able to easily extend this using [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call) and [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) so that the returned function takes a variable number of arguments.